# if datediff equal 1 hour, update table

Tags: sql, sql-server

alrighty--i've never used datediff before, and I'm kinda a morron when it comes to sql, but i'm trying to get this code to work and am having no luck.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('now'));
$sql = "UPDATE starinformation SET starOwner = nextOwner WHERE DATEDIFF(minute, SiegeStart, :date) = 60";
$que = $db->prepare($sql);
$que->bindParam('date', $date);

try{ 
      $que->execute(); 
} catch(PDOException $e) { 
   $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

I want it to update the table where the difference between the two dates is at least 1 hour.

Comment: I take it your using sql server?

Comment: @KevinBowersox Yes Sir.

Comment: It is best to tag your question with `sql-server` to attract those interested in the tag and so everyone knows your db flavor.

Comment: Just to understand what you're trying to do, based on what you show:  you want to update all records in starinformation where the datediff is 1 minute?  Or do you only want to update one record if the datediff is one minute? Also, right now you have it set to where datediff is 60 minutes.

Comment: No i want to update it where the datediff is an hour.
@Tom

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
$que->bindParam('date', $date);
```

to this:

```
$que->bindValue(':date', $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question title, you need to change the query to

```
$sql = "UPDATE starinformation SET starOwner = nextOwner WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, SiegeStart, :date) = 1";
```

Secondly, please ensure that SiegeStart is later than :date, else the result will be negative since the DATEDIFF parameters are Interval, StartDate and EndDate.

Comment: This still isn't working for some reason. I'm starting to think its something somewhere else in my code.

Comment: Did you try directly running this query from SQL Server Management Studio/elsewhere? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you state "I want it to update the table where the difference between the two dates is **at least 1 hour**" (emphasis added).

To do this you will want to compare minutes to `>= 60`. I would strongly recommend against using `DATEDIFF(hour, ..) >= 1`. Reason being that `DATEDIFF()` uses boundaries.

e.g.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, '2014-02-14 08:59:59', '2014-02-14 09:00:00')
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, '2014-02-14 08:59:59', '2014-02-14 09:00:00')
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, '2014-02-14 08:59:59', '2014-02-14 09:00:00')
```

The result is 1 for all 3, as you crossed 1 hour boundary, 1 minute boundary, 1 second boundary. This comes as a surprise to many.

If your code is still not doing what you want, run a SQL Profiler to catch the SQL it is running, and manually run that SQL to see the result. This will often show any issues with a generated SQL statement that are hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query as follows:

```
$sql = "UPDATE starinformation SET starOwner = nextOwner WHERE DATEDIFF(minute, SiegeStart, :date) >= 60";
```